# Set group width depending on content

Tags: kineticjs

I want to use KineticJs, and I am writing a function which is like `position:absolute;right:...px` for the element Group() with kineticJS, I do like this :

```
right : function(dist){
        this.x(250-this.width()-dist);
    }
```

(250 is the container width)
But the width of the group element is 0, even if I use group.add(image).
I would like to know if there is a way to have the width of the Group, in this case it will be the width of the image in the group.
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a function that resizes the group based on its children's sizes:

Example code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/3bz2L/

```
function resizeGroupToContents(group){
    var width=0;
    var height=0; 
    group.getChildren().each(function(node){
        var right=node.x()+node.width();
        if(right>width){width=right;}
        var bottom=node.y()+node.height();
        if(bottom>height){height=bottom;}
    });
    group.width(width);
    group.height(height);
    layer.draw();
}
```